# Preg_match for exact phone number match

Tags: php, regex

```
expected_Phone_number: (888) 888-8888
actual_phone_number: (888) 888-8888
```

How do I use Preg_match to check if the 2 numbers match.(I need to check if the 2 phone numbers match exactly)

Comment: What do you mean by exact? Does it mean with the same formatting (like spaces and dashes)?

Comment: Are the strings always going to be in the format (888) 888-8888 ?

Comment: I tried doing preg_match('/^expected_phone_number$/', actual_phone_number) and it returned me '0' saying its not an exact match. I am not sure how to do it. My test case is to match if the phone number in the DOM is exactly the same as the phone number i give in my "expected_phone_number" variable - and yes it has to be in the exact format as what is in the expected - with bracked, spaces and hyphen

Answer (score 1):

If php supports `\Q .. \E`,  something like

```
'~^\Q' . $phone_number_expected . '\E$~';
```

otherwise regex escape the phone number

```
'~^' . preg_quote($phone_number_expected, '~') . '$~';
```

or just do a string compare